# animate a moving sprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

i know how to animate a sprite using cocos2d , with a spritesheet and plist .

i have a world, and the sprite can move in this world when forces applied .

i need to animate that sprite, while is moving , lets say he falls down, so his eyes should be blinking while he falls ,or move etc..

my code to animate now is this, when i insert a new sprite, but i need to apply it on a specific sprite ,not on a specific place ...

```
-(void)animation:(NSString *)animation
{


    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist",animation]];
    sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_00000.png",animation]]; //take the corrdinates of this picture from the plist

    //sprite.position=ccp(240,160);
    //sprite.position=ccp(160,175);

    CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [ CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",animation]];
    [spriteSheet addChild:sprite]; //add this coordinates from the spritesheet to the screen
    [self addChild:spriteSheet];


    NSString *Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSString *animPath = [Path stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist", animation]];
    NSDictionary *animSpriteCoords = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: animPath];
    NSDictionary *animFramesData = [animSpriteCoords objectForKey:@"frames"];
    int b=0;
    int a=0;
    NSMutableArray *animFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(int i = 1; i < [animFramesData count]; i++) 

    {
        a=a+1;
        if(a==10)
        {
            b=b+1;
            a=0;
        }

        CCSpriteFrame *frame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_000%0i%1i.png",animation,b,a]];   //[NSString stringWithFormat:@"eye_blinking_0000%1d.png",i]
        [animFrames addObject:frame];
    }

    CCAnimate *Action ;
    CCAnimation* dollAnimation = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:animFrames delay:0.1f];
    Action = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:dollAnimation];
    id call=[CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(finishAnimation)];
    id sequence=[CCSequence actions:Action,[CCHide action],call,nil];
    [sprite runAction:sequence];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the animation to walk when it start to move and change when stop in [sprite runAction:sequence];